# Eigenvector. Implementing Jacobi algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matrix, eigenvector, wolframalpha

I am implementing Jacobi algorithms, to get eigenvectors of symmetric matrix. I don't understand why i gain different eigenvector from my applications (same result like mine here: http://fptchlx02.tu-graz.ac.at/cgi-bin/access.com?c1=0000&c2=0000&c3=0000&file=0638) and diffrent from Wolfram Aplha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvector%7B%7B1%2C2%2C3%7D%2C%7B2%2C2%2C1%7D%2C%7B3%2C1%2C1%7D%7D

Example matrix:

```
1 2 3
2 2 1 
3 1 1
```

My Result:

```
0.7400944496522529, 0.6305371413491765, 0.23384421945632447
-0.20230251371232585, 0.5403584533063043, -0.8167535949636785
-0.6413531776951003, 0.5571668060588798, 0.5274763043839444
```

Result from WA:

```
1.13168, 0.969831, 1 
-1.15396, 0.315431, 1 
0.443327, -1.54842, 1
```

I expect that solution is trivial, but i can't find it. I've asked this question on mathoverflow and they pointed me to this site.

Comment: I think this has nothing at all to do with programming

Comment: You can improve your question and make it useful to others if you add the queries that you ran in WA, and also cross-reference your question on Math Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eigenvectors of a matrix are not unique, and there are multiple possible decompositions; in fact, only eigenspaces can be defined uniquely. Both results that you are receiving are valid. You can easily see that by asking Wolfram Alpha to orthogonalize the second matrix. [Run the following query](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Orthogonalize%5B%7B%7B1.13168%2C%200.969831%2C%201.%7D%2C%20%7B-1.15396%2C%200.315431%2C%201.%7D%2C%20%7B0.443327%2C%20-1.54842%2C%201.%7D%7D%5D):

```
Orthogonalize[{{1.13168, 0.969831, 1.}, {-1.15396, 0.315431, 1.}, {0.443327, -1.54842, 1.}}]
```

to obtain

```
 0.630537    0.540358    0.557168
-0.740094    0.202306    0.641353
 0.233844   -0.816754    0.527475
```

Now you can see that your algorithm returns a correct result. First, the matrix is transposed: WA gave you row vectors, and your algorithm returns them in columns. Then, the first vector is multiplied by a -1, but any eigenvector can be multiplied by a non-zero constant to yield a valid eigenvector. Otherwise, the results perfectly match.

You may also find the following Mathematics StackExchange answer helpful: [Are the eigenvectors of a real symmetric matrix always an orthonormal basis without change?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/157406/22961)

Comment: Yes, You are right. Thanks for Your answer, not trivial for me as i expect but I understood it.